# com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition (Assertions.java:82)

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Getting **com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition (Assertions.java:82)** in firebase Crashlytics console.

```
   com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition (Assertions.java:82)
    com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onHostPause (ReactInstanceManager.java:596)
    com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onHostPause (ReactDelegate.java:63)
    com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onPause (ReactActivityDelegate.java:96)
    com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onPause (ReactActivity.java:52)
    android.app.Activity.performPause (Activity.java:8096)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause (Instrumentation.java:1508)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded (ActivityThread.java:4585)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4540)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity (ActivityThread.java:4489)
    android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute (PauseActivityItem.java:46)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2047)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7592)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
```

Comment: Any updates on this solution?